# Convergence of recurrence relation

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, continuity, solution-verification, recurrence-relations

How can I prove that the following recurrence relation converges to 2:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{3a_n}{\operatorname{gcd}(2^{a_n},a_n)}+1$$
When $a_0$ is even.
According to a similar post it can be easily proven if $a_n$ is to converge it will converge to 2 however I don't know how I can prove its convergence. In case it is useful, a continuous form of the recurrence is:
$$a(x+1)=e^{x}\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k}f(k)}{x-k}$$
Where $f(x)$ is:
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{3x}{\gcd\left(2^{x},x\right)}+1$$

Answer (score 2):

The exponent of $2$ appearing in the factorization of $a_n$ will always be smaller than $a_n$ ([Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)).

This means that, if we write $a_n = 2^v m$ with $m$ odd, then $\gcd(2^{a_n}, a_n)$ is simply $2^v$, and the right hand side of the formula is $m + 1$, which is again even.

Given that $a_0$ is even, we immediately know that all $a_n$ are even.

Now it only remains to remark that $a_{n + 1}$ is strictly smaller than $a_n$ whenever $a_n > 2$ is even.

Comment: The problem then arises then that for some values of $n$, $a_{n + 1}>a_n$ and for some other values $a_n>a_{n + 1}$.

Comment: Why? As long as $a_n > 2$, it will always decrease. Eventually $a_n$ becomes $2$ and all terms afterwards are all $2$.

Comment: Sorry, just realized a mistype